# 2D array C++ operator []

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a 2D array, when I want to assign a value to a cell, it assigns the same value to the opposite cell.

Here's an example :

```
g.tab = new MyType*[g.width];
for(int i=0;i<g.height;i++) {
    g.tab[i] = new MyType;
}
const int x = 0;
const int y = 1;    
g.tab[x][y].b = true;
```

The value at g.tab[0][1] and g.tab[1][0] will be the same.

I don't know why...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can't you use `std::vector`? It won't solve the problem you have (which is answered by Mike Seymour) but using vectors instead of pointers for "dynamic arrays" will make your life as a C++ programmer much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're allocating `width` pointers; then allocating a single element for `height` of them. You presumably want to allocate `height` elements for each one:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < g.width; ++i) {
    g.tab[i] = new MyType[g.height];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant:

```
for(int i=0;i<g.width;i++)
g.tab[i] = new MyType[g.height];
```

By writing `g.tab[i] = new MyType;` you didn't allocate a 2D array.

And depending on the `heigth`, the `i<g.heigth;` condition would either compile but not work correctly, or cause some kind of a memory access violation.